# Obtener mi propia IP

Tags: php

Tenemos servidores en la nube que nos cobran por el tiempo que están prendidos (por tal motivo los apagamos con frecuencia), al volver a prender cambian las IP de cada server.

El detalle es que en uno montamos un sitio wordpress en el que solo accedemos en intranet, pero al cambiar la IP cada vez que se vuelven a prender, hay que entrar manualmente a la base de datos en wp_options a cambiar el IP de siteurl y home.

Entonces hemos optado por hacer un query update para que haga ese cambio de IP en la BD automáticamente vía PHP, pero para ello primero necesitamos saber la IP pública del server para almacenarlo en la variable de inserción.

Espero que me puedan ayudar, gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Para evitar el cierre de tu pregunta lee [ask], edita y agrega que llevas al momento

Comment: Mirate la variable `$_SERVER` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15699101/get-the-client-ip-address-using-php#15699240

Answer (score 1):

Para eso lo más sencillo es usar esto:

`$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];`